# Howto fix my PHP install on FreeBSD using pkg

Tags: freebsd, php

I've been messing around with `pkg install`, installing / removing both `php5-5.4.29` and `php55-5.5.13`.

But when I run `php` from the command line, it will give me an error like this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/local/lib/php/20100525/memcache.so' - 
/usr/local/lib/php/20100525/memcache.so: Undefined symbol 
"php_session_create_id" in Unknown on line 0
```

If I try the 5.5.13 version, the error is this:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20121212/posix.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20121212/posix.so" in Unknown on line 0`

Anyone have some tips how I can clean the mess I've made and do a fresh install of `php55-5.5.13` ?

EDIT:
I also noticed that an old php version from the ports is installed, which seems to be conflicting with the pkg one. But trying to (re)install from ports will give me:

`PHP xx doesn't install the Apache module anymore: update your OPTIONS and build www/mod_php5 port instead`

Comment: Try creating that folder first.

Comment: made no difference

Comment: Run `php-config` and check your `--extension-dir` path.  You may need to change the installation directory with `./configure --prefix=DIR` or something. There's a really good guide here. http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/build_system/building_php.html Just realized how old this question is.

Answer (score 1):

`pkg install mod_php5` should take care of it.

Comment: I get a long list of warnings like these: pkg: WARNING: locally installed php55-5.5.13 conflicts on /usr/local/man/man1/phpize.1.gz with:
        - php5-5.4.29

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear from your question which version of PHP you were actually wanting to use. If you want php 5.4, install mod_php5. If you want php 5.5, install mod_php55. I would not try to install both.

Comment: Well the installing is no problem, it's getting rid of the old PHP that's the problem it seems (the one once installed by ports collection)